# Simplify the expression $\dfrac{\sqrt{3+a}}{\sqrt{3+a}-\sqrt{3-a}}+\dfrac{3-a}{\sqrt{9-a^2}-3+a}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify the expression $$\dfrac{\sqrt{3+a}}{\sqrt{3+a}-\sqrt{3-a}}+\dfrac{3-a}{\sqrt{9-a^2}-3+a}$$
I don't see anything, so I tried to rationalize the denominators. We should multiply the first term by
$\dfrac{\sqrt{3+a}+\sqrt{3-a}}{\sqrt{3+a}+\sqrt{3-a}}$. How to rationalize the second denominator?

Comment: How about $$\frac{3-a}{\sqrt{9-a}-|\sqrt{(3-a)^2}|}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we write $b = \sqrt{3+a}$ and $c = \sqrt{3-a}$ then we have $$...={b\over b-c} +  {c^2\over cb-c^2}= {b+c\over b-c}= {(b+c)^2\over b^2-c^2}={3+\sqrt{9-a^2}\over a}$$

Comment: Thanks! How did you get $\dfrac{b+c}{b-c},$ tho? I don't see it.

Comment: Cancel c in the second fraction and you get the same denumerator

Comment: Thanks! May I also ask why $$\dfrac{b+c}{b-c}=\dfrac{(b+c)^2}{b^2-c^2}$$ What was the intuition that led to this approach?

Comment: Rationalization .... remember that $b$ and $c$ are square roots.

Answer (score 1):

You can observe that $\sqrt{3-a}\sqrt{3+a} =\sqrt{9-a^2}$ and $\sqrt{3
+a}\sqrt{3+a} =3+a$.

So multiply and divide the first term by $\sqrt{3+a} $ to get,

$\dfrac{3+a}{3+a-\sqrt{9-a^2}} = -\dfrac{3+a}{\sqrt{9-a^2}-3+a}$

---

Or you can do the same process in reverse with the second term to get

$\dfrac{3-a}{\sqrt{9-a^2}-3+a} =\dfrac{\sqrt{3-a}\sqrt{3-a}}{\sqrt{3+a}\sqrt{3-a}-\sqrt{3-a}\sqrt{3-a}}= \dfrac{\sqrt{3-a}}{\sqrt{3+a}-\sqrt{3-a}}$

On doing some further simplifications, you'll get $\dfrac{3+\sqrt{9-a^{2}}}{a}$

Comment: That is actually a better thought than mine